# How does batch normalization make a model less sensitive to hyperparameter tuning?

Tags: hyperparameter-tuning, batch-normalization, generalization

Question 22 of [100+ Data Science Interview Questions and Answers for 2022](https://www.projectpro.io/article/100-data-science-interview-questions-and-answers-for-2021/184) asks *What is the benefit of batch normalization?*

The first bullet of the answers to this is *The model is less sensitive to hyperparameter tuning.*

The wikipedia page [batch normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_normalization) similarly claims:

> Furthermore, batch normalization seems to have a regularizing effect such that the network improves its generalization properties, and it is thus unnecessary to use dropout to mitigate overfitting.

In both cases I suspect they are referring to improved test error, with the former involving improved test error even having done some hyperparameter tuning.

Why does batch normalization have a regularizing effect? (Or does it?)

Answer (score 1):

Regularization is not the primary goal of batch normalization. The main goal of batch normalization is to speed up learning. Regularization is a side effect of batch normalization, it does not replace dropout.

As normalizing inputs improves learning, normalizing aggregated inputs to the activation function of a neuron in a hidden layer improves learning as well. More details [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNIpEZLv_eg), and then [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=em6dfRxYkYU).

If during batch training, you normalize the aggregated inputs to hidden activations for the batch rather than for the whole dataset, then the mean and standard deviations of the aggregated inputs will be different for each batch. This will add noise to the training, and make the network to rely less on smaller details of the distribution of the inputs.

However, the regularization effect of batch normalization depends on the batch size. It is lower for larger batch sizes, and is lower than the effect of dropout which shuts down some neurons completely for a training step, so it probably cannot replace dropout. More details [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUUqwaxLnWs).